# CSS navigation background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a custom CSS navigation for my website but I have some problems you can find the code sniped bellow.
I am making a CSS vertical navigation here is the code:

```
<style type="text/css">

/* GT stylesheet */
#cssmenu > ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;
line-height: 1;
}

/* The container */
#cssmenu > ul {
display: block;
position: relative;
width: 150px;
}

/* The list elements which contain the links */
#cssmenu > ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;   
}

    /* General link styling */
    #cssmenu > ul li a {
        /* Layout */
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0;
        border-top: 1px dotted #3a3a3a;
        border-bottom: 1px dotted #1b1b1b;
        padding: 11px 20px;
        width: 210px;

        /* Typography */
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #d8d8d8;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;


        /* Background & effects */
        background: #282828;
    }

    /* Rounded corners for the first link of the menu/submenus */
    #cssmenu > ul li:first-child>a {
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-top: 0;
    }

    /* Rounded corners for the last link of the menu/submenus */
    #cssmenu > ul li:last-child>a {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom: 0;
    }


    /* The hover state of the menu/submenu links */
    #cssmenu > ul li>a:hover, #cssmenu > ul li:hover>a {
        color: #000;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
        background: #A9CA6F;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #A9CA6F, #B4D876);
        background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #A9CA6F, #B4D876); 
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #A9CA6F, #B4D876);
        background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #A9CA6F, #B4D876);
        border-color: transparent;
    }

    /* The arrow indicating a submenu */
    #cssmenu > ul .has-sub>a::after {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 16px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;

        /* Creating the arrow using borders */
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #d8d8d8; 
    }

    /* The same arrow, but with a darker color, to create the shadow effect */
    #cssmenu > ul .has-sub>a::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 17px;
        right: 10px;
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;

        /* Creating the arrow using borders */
        border: 4px solid transparent;
        border-left: 4px solid #000;
    }

    /* Changing the color of the arrow on hover */
    #cssmenu > ul li>a:hover::after, #cssmenu > ul li:hover>a::after {
        border-left: 4px solid #fff;
    }

    #cssmenu > ul li>a:hover::before, #cssmenu > ul li:hover>a::before {
        border-left: 4px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    }
</style>
```

The problem is that I cannot make the link I clicked on to change its background to: #A9CA6F.
I want when I make my `<li>` with id/class active to stay with this color: #A9CA6F
Any help?

Thanks in advance!

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WT9Uw/) this is the link for the fiddle!

Comment: Can you post your HTML and javascript too. Also consider creating a fiddle for this question

Comment: See the edit version of the question and find the link demo in the end of the it

Comment: Are you using a server side language?  this will most likely need to be done via that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this...

```
#cssmenu li.active a {background-color:#A9CA6F;}
```

I think all you need to do is add the background-color to the `a` and target it quite specifically. Here's the fiddle - I've added a line at the bottom of your CSS. If you don't target it specifically enough it won't overrule the default style.

EDIT

To elaborate slightly, previously in your CSS you have stated:

```
#cssmenu > ul li a {...}
```

So in order to target your active class you must be *more* specific than this, otherwise the above rule will override all others - hence:

```
#cssmenu > ul li.active a {...}
```

and not...

```
li.active a  {...}
```

So, for example, in a no-holds-barred fight between CSS rules...

1. `#menu a` would beat `a.active`
2. `a.active` would beat just `a`
3. `#wrapper #menu a` would beat `#menu a`

:-) HTH

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sarfarazdesigner/WT9Uw/3/

```
#cssmenu > ul li.active > a, #cssmenu > ul li.active > a {
   background-color:#A9CA6F;            
   color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it via some javascript if it is going to navigate also inside the same page.
Here is a jQuery solution:

```
$("#cssmenu li").click(function(){
    $("#cssmenu li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WT9Uw/2/)

It moves the `.active` class to whatever `li` has been clicked.
And in CSS you can add a selector that looks something like that (to your hover selectors):

```
#cssmenu > ul li.active a
```

Comment: I disagree - if the page is reloaded when the visitor clicks (which is a fairly safe assumption) then this should be done server side. If fresh content is going to be loaded into the same page via ajax then the best solution will be pure CSS `#cssmenu > ul li a:active` (untested)

Comment: @Doug sometimes you just want to navigate up and down a long page for example, then this is the only way really. And I believe the `:active` pseudo selector will only apply the style while the link/button is actually being pressed down. And if the page gets reloaded the active class will be applied as it has been so far.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, @Martin Turjak - my bad, the :active pseudoclass only works when the link is actually being clicked and it doesn't persist. However, the OP didn't ask about being able to navigate verically on the same page - only being able to change the background colour of the link marked as `.active`

Comment: Well, I offer the an answer to the styling problem by adding the selector to the CSS as well as a jQuery solution **if** the nav is going to navigate also inside the same page, and the OP can decide if that is useful for him at all or not. In my experience a lot of pages today use the side nav excessively to navigate up and down one page.

Answer (score 1):

it's simple add this code:

```
#cssmenu > ul li.active a{
    background-color: #A9CA6F;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WT9Uw/4/)